# PHPMailer not attaching files larger than 100KB - PHP

Tags: php, phpmailer, email-attachments

I am trying to set up a contact form which handles multiple file attachments. I am using PHPMailer and built the below script from the [PHPMailer example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_multiple_file_upload.phps) for attaching multiple files.

The below script works great until attachments exceed 100KB. If a file is larger than 100KB, it is skipped when attaching. Only files smaller than 100KB are attached and sent.

I have seen this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607790/php-mailer-email-is-not-sent-for-more-than-100-kb-attachment) which looked promising, but the values in my machine's `php.ini` file were all set to 32MB or higher.

I am using Mailgun as the SMTP server, and can see in the logs that the attachments that exceed 100KB aren't getting to Mailgun at all so it must have something to do with this script or my PHP environment.

Can anyone help me resolve this?

```php
<?php
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$host = 'smtp.mailgun.org';
$username = 'postmaster@domain.com';
$password = 'password';

$email_from = 'from@domain.com';
$email_to = 'to@domain.com';

$send = false;

$subject = "Quote Request from Website";

$name = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['name']));
$email = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
$project_type = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['project_type']));
$message = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['message']));

$htmlmessage = <<<MESSAGE
    <html>
        <head>
              <title>$subject</title>
        </head>

        <body>
            <p><strong>Name:</strong> $name</p>
            <p><strong>Email:</strong> $email</p>
            <p><strong>Project Type:</strong> $project_type</p>
            <p><strong>Message:</strong> $message</p>
        </body>
    </html>
MESSAGE;

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = $username;
$mail->Password = $password;
$mail->Host = $host;
$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->setFrom($email_from, $name);
$mail->addAddress($email_to);
$mail->addReplyTo($email, $name);
// $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
// $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

// Attach multiple files one by one
$total = count($_FILES['attachments']['tmp_name']);
echo $total;
for ($ct = 0; $ct < $total; $ct++)
{
    $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['attachments']['name'][$ct]));
    $filename = $_FILES['attachments']['name'][$ct];
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachments']['tmp_name'][$ct], $uploadfile)) {
        echo $filename;
        $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename);
    } else {
        $msg .= 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
        echo $msg;
    }

    // $name = $_FILES['attachments']['name'][$ct];
    // $path = $_FILES['attachments']['tmp_name'][$ct];
    // echo $name . ' - ' . $path . '<br>';
    // $mail->addAttachment($path, $name);
}

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body    = $htmlmessage;
// $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

The form:

```
<form action="contact/quote.php" method="post" id="quote-form" class="validate" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>

  <label>Email</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>

  <label>Project Type</label>
  <select name="project_type" id="project_type" required>
    <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
  </select>

  <label>Upload Files</label>
  <input multiple="multiple" type="file" name="attachments[]" value="">

  <label>Message</label>
  <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="5" required></textarea>

  <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `MAX_FILE_SIZE` option in your form, which won't help, and it defaults to 100k, which exactly matches what you're seeing. [See the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

[The send_file_upload example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps) shows how to set it correctly.

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000">
```